# What are descriptors

Tags: r, data, visualization

I am very new to data science, and r programming specifically. Could some explain what a descriptor in data science is? In particular, what are the differences between a 2d and 3d descriptor?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

In data science, a **descriptor** is a ***mathematical function that maps a dataset to a fixed-size vector***. This vector can then be used **to represent the dataset in a lower-dimensional space**, which is often useful for various data analysis tasks such as *clustering, classification, and visualization*.

**Descriptors** are often **used in pattern recognition** and **machine learning algorithms** *to summarize and analyze data in a compact and useful form*. The **dimensionality** of the descriptor vector *depends on the specific function used to map the data to the vector*.

A **2D descriptor** is a mathematical representation of data that has **two dimensions**, such as an **image that has a width and a height**. For example, a **2D descriptor** for a dataset of images might *map each image to a vector containing the average intensity of the pixels in the image, and the standard deviation of the pixel intensities*.

A **3D descriptor**, on the other hand, has *three dimensions*, such as a **3D point cloud or a volume of voxels**. For example, a **3D descriptor** for the same dataset might add a *third dimension to the vector*, such as the **number of edges in the image**.

In general, **higher-dimensional descriptors** can capture more information about the dataset, but they also **require more computational resources** to compute and may not always be necessary for a given task. The choice of **descriptor** can have a **significant impact on the performance** of a machine learning algorithm, so it is important to choose an appropriate descriptor that *captures the relevant features of the data*.